# How does the 'new' messages concept work?

Tags: client-side

On a forum or email client you can see the difference between the old and the new messages by style (the new messages from the last visit are bold for example).

Can you tell me - How is that implemented?

Comment: Very hard to answer since the implementation on a forum is completely diffrent from the implementation on a desktop client, e.g. Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a straightforward question... it depends on the e-mail client you are using.

In the case of Mozilla Thunderbird, we can easily [view the source online](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/suite/themes/modern/messenger/threadPane.css) to check it out. The way they do it is by applying a different style in their stylesheet for read vs. unread messages:

```
47 treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(read) {
48   font-weight: normal;
49 }
50 
51 treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(unread) {
52   font-weight: bold;
53 }
```

Somehow they get the "unread" flag from the data store up to the UI presentation layer and apply the correct style based on if the message is read or unread. How they do *that* is left as an exercise to the reader. ;-)

Comment: by default is set to unread and the client modify the status. That's smart. TY.